# Starting webdriver faster Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to start the chromedriver faster in Selenium?
It's taking about 6 seconds for it to actually start and thats literally half the runtime of my code.

Comment: it's depend on your pc

Comment: what is your pc specs?

Answer (score 0):

Check [ChromeDriverService](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) that will reduce the launching time. And you will see the diff when you have multiple tests running.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using ChromeDriverService.
When we use ChromeDriver class, it starts/terminates the ChromeDriver server process which can waste a significant amount of time for large test suites whereas ChromeDriver instance is created per test.

or we can start the Chrome-driver server separately before running tests, and connect to it using the Remote WebDriver

please refer official documantation at
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started